# Functors similar to $H^i(\cdot)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, cohomology

Suppose $T$ is a contravariant functor from the category of pointed topological spaces to the category of abelian groups, then we have homomorphisms $\alpha\colon T(X)\times T(Y)\to T(X\times Y)$ and $\beta\colon T(X\times Y)\to T(X)\times T(Y)$.(Induced by projections and inclusions $\pi\colon X\times Y\to X$ and $i\colon X\to X\times \{y_0\}$)

(1) Then do we have $T(X\times Y)=\textrm{Im}\alpha\oplus \textrm{ker}\beta$?

(The functor does not necessarily send a point to the $0$ group, such as $0$-th singular cohomology functor, so we may not have $\beta\circ\alpha=1$)

Further, in case with three variables, we have $\alpha\colon T(X\times Y)\times T(Y\times Z)\times T(Z\times X)\to T(X\times Y\times Z)$ and vice versa $\beta$.

(2) Do we have $T(X\times Y\times Z)=\textrm{Im}\alpha\oplus \textrm{ker}\beta$

Comment: What happens if you proceed as one does in your cohomology example? Define a reduced version $\tilde{T}(X)$ as the kernel of the map $T(X)\to T(pt)$. Then one has a canonical splitting $T(X)=\tilde{T}(X)\oplus T(pt)$.

Comment: It's a good point! But I still can't show the case with three variables even if knowing $T(pt)$ is $0$.

Comment: @user69091 Yes we can reduce to the case $T(pt)=0$ then prove it! Thanks!